# Is there another way than using databases of FTP to share data?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ftp, data-sharing

I was just wondering if there is another way to share data that just via FTP or databases. If I wanna do for example app with self-destructive messages (like snapchat) wouldn't it be easier to just send it "once" to a specific device? I hope that you understand what I'm saying.

Tnx and happy coding <3

Comment: Sorry, no, it is not really clear what you mean or ask. However I will make a _wild guess_: If this is about that you want to prevent a central database and exchange messages as files instead directly between computers, then the answer is clear: that is not really possible, the main reason for that: the network topology, so how the internet works. you simply cannot reach the clients which actually is a very good thing from a security point of view.

Comment: You do seriously need to expand your question with more details of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider cloud services for such usage.
Or simply store same date in file and rewrite it later. 
There's a lot of approaches.

(Still can't comment)